# Как на java подменить код библиотеки?

Tags: java

Есть библиотека которая использует `HashMap` из стандартной библиотеки. Как можно сделать так, чтобы она использовала мой `HashMap`? Код библиотеки трогать нельзя.

Comment: переопределить классы библиотеки, которые используют hashmap

Comment: @Maxgmer код библиотеки трогать нельзя.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev он его и не трогает, он его дополняет своим классом

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev а вообще было бы круто пояснить тогда, что значит нельзя трогать, я понимаю нельзя трогать как "нельзя декомпилить артефакт библиотеки и писать туда свой код"

Comment: @Maxgmer самому интересно. Может автор нам таки расскажет. Но на сколько я понял, у него ситуация, подобная наличию jar-файла с финальными классами и без исходников.

Comment: Есть библиотека и ей занимается другая команда из другой фирмы. Могут обновить и принести другую версию спокойно в которой не будет изменений импортов. Ну и к тому же у нас просто jar файл.

Comment: `HashMap` в сторонней библиотеке используется как? То есть передается на вход метода/конструктора от клиента(то есть из Вашего кода) или создается внутри самих методов библиотеки?

Comment: Создаётся внутри библиотеки. Они не используют фабрики а напрямую вызывают конструктор.

Answer (score 4):

- Если есть класс и в нем поле типа HashMap:
  Тогда перед началом использования библиотеки воспользоваться Reflection API и просетать свою реализацию.
- Если HashMap создаются как локальные переменные методов:
  Здесь можно воспользоваться Java Agent

  ```
  public class HashMapTransformationAgent {

  public static void premain(String agentArgument, Instrumentation instrumentation) {
      System.out.println("I am javaagent Counter");
      instrumentation.addTransformer(new HashMapClassTransformer());
  }
  }
  ```

  Полезная статья про Java Agent https://habr.com/post/230239/
  "Он будет запущен еще перед запуском вашего приложения. Сам агент это отдельное приложение которое предоставляет доступ к механизму манипуляции байт-кодом (java.lang.instrument) в runtime."  В ClassFileTransformer можно использовать библиотеки Javaassist или Java ASM. Java ASM более низкоуровневая http://www.baeldung.com/java-asm.
  Пример с Javaassist, замеряем время работы метода put.

  ```
  public class HashMapClassTransformer implements ClassFileTransformer {

  private static int count = 0;

  @Override
  public byte[] transform(ClassLoader loader,
                          String className,
                          Class<?> classBeingRedefined,
                          ProtectionDomain protectionDomain,
                          byte[] classfileBuffer) throws IllegalClassFormatException {

      System.out.println("load class: " + className.replaceAll("/", "."));
      System.out.println(String.format("loaded %s classes", ++count));

      String ctClassName = className.replaceAll("/", ".");
      try {
          if(ctClassName.equals("java.util.HashMap")) {
              // Javassist
              try {
                  ClassPool cp = ClassPool.getDefault();
                  CtClass cc = cp.get(ctClassName);
                  CtMethod m = cc.getDeclaredMethod("put");
                  m.addLocalVariable("elapsedTime", CtClass.longType);
                  m.insertBefore(
                          "elapsedTime = System.currentTimeMillis();"
                                  //+ "long a = 5000l;"
                                  + "Thread.sleep(1000l);"
                  );
                  m.getMethodInfo().getAttributes();
                  m.insertAfter(
                          "{elapsedTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - elapsedTime;"
                                  + "System.out.println(\"Method Executed in ms: \" + elapsedTime);}"
                  );
                  byte[] byteCode = cc.toBytecode();
                  cc.detach();
                  return byteCode;
              } catch (Exception ex) {
                  ex.printStackTrace();
              }
          }
      } catch (Exception e){
          System.out.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
      }

      return classfileBuffer;
  }
  }
  ```

  Но минус данного подхода в том, что теперь весь ваш код, а не только сторонняя библиотека, будет использовать кастомный HashMap.

Comment: А первый способ как реализовать?

Comment: http://www.quizful.net/post/java-reflection-api, там есть пример с установлением нового значения private полям

Answer (score 2):

Есть несколько разных способов, а сама ситуация довольно тривиальна. У вас нет возможности получить исходники и собрать вручную новый jar-ник, а обычно никто просто не хочет сам пересобирать проект, подключать его как модуль или как-то ещё терять возможность использовать зависимость, прописав одну строчку в конфигурационном файле. Один из способов я опишу ниже, им в случае крайней необходимости пользуюсь сам и,  по моему скромному мнению, он не выглядит как костыль.

Способ заключается в простом: если класс не `final` и от него можно отнаследоваться таким образом, чтобы можно было безболезненно изменить все нужные части и иметь возможность дальше прокидывать «ребёнка» под видом инстанса самого класса, то так и стоит поступить. Просто экстендимся, переопределяем все нужные части и так далее. Если поля `private`, или всё жёстко друг с другом связано — можно перейти к пункту 2. Но нередко и такой способ может помочь. В этом случае вы не теряете возможность получения обновлений используемой библиотеки, не лезете в её код, не пользуетесь рефлексией и прочими радостями жизни Java-разработчика.

Второй способ чуть сложнее. Логично, что даже если вы назовёте класс также, прокинуть его под видом класса библиотеки не получится, и вы наткнётесь, что встроить свою реализацию нужного класса не получится просто так. В этом случае вы просто копируете нужный класс, производите нужные манипуляции (меняете тип полей, входные параметры и вообще любую логику) и берёте все классы, которые жёстко привязывают к использованию изменённого класса. Переписываете и их, меняя лишь тип параметра в нужных местах. Если библиотека написана нормально, то уровень абстракции должен позволить поменять не более пары-тройки классов кроме непосредственно самого, который вы меняли. И то, в них придётся поменять по паре строк кода.

---

Мне приходилось заниматься подобным не раз, когда хотелось встроить свою сложную или специфичную логику в код библиотеки, но это нельзя было сделать просто прокинув куда-то свой класс, имплементящий нужный интерфейс, а клонить её всю и менять её сорцы — последнее, к чему я бы прибегнул, особенно, если библиотека немаленькая и часто обновляется.